# How to run Uvicorn FastAPI server as a module from another Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to run FastAPI server using Uvicorn from A different Python file.

**uvicornmodule/main.py**

```
import uvicorn
import webbrowser
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
st_abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "static/")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=st_abs_file_path), name="static")

@app.get("/")
async def index():
    return FileResponse('static/index.html', media_type='text/html')

def start_server():
    # print('Starting Server...')       

    uvicorn.run(
        "app",
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=8765,
        log_level="debug",
        reload=True,
    )
    # webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8765")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

So, I want to run the FastAPI server from the below `test.py` file:

```
from uvicornmodule import main
main.start_server()
```

Then, I run `python test.py`.

But I am getting the below error:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

What I am doing wrong? I need to run this module as package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When spawning new processes from the main process (as this is what happens when `uvicorn.run()` is called), it is important to protect the entry point to avoid recursive spawning of subprocesses, etc. As described in [this article](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-spawn-runtimeerror/):

> If the entry point was not protected with an if-statement idiom
> checking for the top-level environment, then the script **would execute
> again directly**, rather than run a new child process as expected.
>
> Protecting the entry point ensures that the program is only started
> once, that the tasks of the main process are only executed by the main
> process and not the child processes.

Basically, your code that creates the new process must be under [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). Hence:

```py
from uvicornmodule import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main.start_server()
```

Additionally, [running `uvicorn` programmatically](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-programmatically) and having `reload` and/or `workers` flag(s) enabled, you **must** pass the application as an import string in the format of `"<module>:<attribute>"`. For example:

```py
# main.py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

As a sidenote, the below would also work, if `reload` and/or `workers` flags were not used:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Also, as per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#first-steps), when running the server from a terminal in the following way (the default `port` is `8000`. Have a look at all the available [command line options](https://www.uvicorn.org/#command-line-options)):

```
> uvicorn main:app --reload
```

the command `uvicorn main:app` refers to:

> - `main`: the file `main.py` (the Python "module").
> - `app`: the object created inside of `main.py` with the line `app = FastAPI()`.
> - `--reload`: make the server restart after code changes. **Only use for development**.

Comment: if I want to run start_server method without including it on main how can I do that? Or anything we can modify main.py so that we can start directly fastapi server

Comment: You don't really have to include `start_server()` inside `main.py`. You could instead move that method inside `test.py`, if you wish. The first argument in  `uvicorn.run()`, i.e., `"<module>:<attribute>"` is what specifies where the app you would like to run is located, as described in the answer above. You can always [run your application through command line](https://www.uvicorn.org/#usage) as well.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR;

Use **`uvicorn.run('parent_dir.child_dir.grand_son_dir.main:Application', reload=True)`**

> Notice directories separated by a `dot`
>
> in a nutshell this should be : `'<module>.<sub_mod>.<sub_mod>:<app_name>'`

### LR;

Example: Consider this project tree

[image]

- `parent_dir/child_dir/grand_son_dir/main.py` is as follow

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
Application = FastAPI()
```

- `main.py` is as follow

```py
import uvicorn
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(
        "parent_dir.child_dir.grand_son_dir.main:Application", reload=True)
```

- Now, from `parent_dir` you can try one of these:

  - `uvicorn 'parent_dir.child_dir.grand_son_dir.main:Application'`

  > OR

  - `python main.py`

> Both will work like charm
> [image]